# What tools come pre-installed on Mac; what is part of the Xcode command line tools; and what should I install myself?

Tags: command-line, xcode, homebrew

I'm setting up my Macbook, and in the process of installing Homebrew, I installed the Xcode commandline tools. I'm assuming the result of this is the /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools directory, which contains a ton of common executables (e.g., git, make, gcc, etc.) in the subdirectory /usr/bin (i.e. /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin).

Many - though not all - of these executables are also found in the /usr/bin directory found in root. What's going on here?

Running which name_of_any_executable always returns /usr/bin, but I wasn't able to execute these before installing the Xcode command line tools. Are the ones in the root /usr/bin just symlinks to what the command line tools installed?

Also, as a follow up, are these system executables safe to use? People always brew install git, for example, but why do that if git (and other popular programs) is already present as a result of installing the Xcode commandline tools?

This is just a broad question that I'm curious to have answered. Is there a resource online somewhere that lists exactly what the xcode command line tools install?

Comment: `pkgutil` is your friend. It will list files installed as packages.